# Now the error disappear but I am still can't get the expected output, the sensorData only return the same value of x,y,z accelerometer.

Tags: android, csv, arraylist, accelerometer, gyroscope

I really need help, I need to write ArrayList of Accelerometer Value into csv, but I got an error java lang indexoutofboundsexception invalid index 1 size is 1. Here is the code:

in here I change the sensor sampling rate within the certain time so it won't be that fast (because fast means a lot of noise):

```
public void SyncSensor(){
if((System.currentTimeMillis()-lastSaved) > ACCE_FILTER_DATA_MIN_TIME) {
    lastSaved = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //displayCleanValues();
    // display the current x,y,z accelerometer values
    //displayCurrentValues();
   }
}
```

After that I want to save the value obtain into some arraylist and then write it into csv file, but this keep giving me an error:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (isRunning) {
        SyncSensor();
        displayCleanValues();

        displayCurrentValues();

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                //float[] values = event.values;
                // get the change of the x,y,z values of the accelerometer
                deltaX = Math.abs(lastX - event.values[0]);
                deltaY = Math.abs(lastY - event.values[1]);
                deltaZ = Math.abs(lastZ - event.values[2]);
                //long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                AccelData data = new AccelData( deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ);
                sensorData.add(data);
                lastSaved = System.currentTimeMillis();
                // if the change is below 2, it is just plain noise
                if (deltaX < 2)
                    deltaX = 0;
                if (deltaY < 2)
                    deltaY = 0;
                if ((deltaZ > vibrateThreshold) || (deltaY > vibrateThreshold) || (deltaZ > vibrateThreshold)) {
                    v.vibrate(50);
                }
        }
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {

            //get the change of the x,y,z values of the accelerometer
            gsx = event.values[0];
            gsy = event.values[1];
            gsz = event.values[2];
        }
        try {
            switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
                case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                    for (int i = 0; i < sensorData.size(); i++) {

                        //long time = sensorData.get(i).getTimestamp();
                        float x = sensorData.get(i).getX(), y = sensorData.get(i).getY(), z = sensorData.get(i).getZ();
                        writer.write(String.format("%d; ACC; %f; %f; %f\n", event.timestamp, x, y, z));
                        break;
                    }

                case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
                    writer.write(String.format("%d; GYRO; %f; %f; %f\n", event.timestamp, gsx, gsy, gsz));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and here is the AccelData class:

```
public class AccelData {
//public long timestamp;
public float x;
public float y;
public float z;

public AccelData( float x, float y, float z){

   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.z = z;
}
//public long getTimestamp(){
 //   return timestamp;
//}

public float getX(){
    return x;
}
public float getY(){
    return y;
}
public float getZ(){
   return z;
}
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is sensorData.get(1)?

Comment: it should get the Y value of accelerometer, so I create another class called AccelData to store and return the value to data.